# How does this JavaScript code sort these numbers?

Tags: javascript, parameters, sorting

Can someone walk me through it? I don't understand what parameters are passed and things like that.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function sortNumber(a, b)
{
return b - a;
}

var n = ["10", "5", "40", "25", "100", "1"];
document.write(n.sort(sortNumber));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` will compare `a` to `b`, and change the array to be in descending order.

The `-` operator will coerce them to `Number`.

If you want to see the members being passed as `a` and `b`, output them with something like `console.log` (if you have a console object).

Comment: @DarkLightA Members of the array.

Comment: @DarkLightA: The `sort` function will call the comparator function you give it repeatedly, to compare two entries from the array as part of the sorting process. In your case, they might be "10" and "100", for instance, since those are two of the entries in your array. Because your code in the function is `return b - a;`, as Alex said, the interpreter sees the `-` and coerces those strings into numbers, and then performs the operation you requested. The return value from the comparator is supposed to be >0 if `a` > `b`, <0 if `a` < `b`, and 0 if `a` == `b`. So `b - a` means `10` is > `100`.

Comment: @TJCrowder +1 for your comment (which itself could be an answer)!

Comment: But otherwise get it from the horse's mouth. read the link posted more than once from mozilla

Answer (score 1):

The function sortNumber will return something less than 0, 0 or something larger than 0. this will tell the sort which of the compared strings are numerically larger

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort